# How many different DNA sequences of length 4 consist of exactly two different letters?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Note: $P(A)=p_A, P(C)=p_C, P(G)=p_G, P(T)=p_T$

My attempt: I tried to make a list of every single possible sequence. How can I solve this question more efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no probability involved here.

---

Number of ways to choose $2$ out of $4$ letters:

$$\binom{4}{2}=6$$

Number of sequences in which the $1^{st}$ letter appears $1$ time and the $2^{nd}$ letter appears $3$ times:

$$\binom{4}{1}=4$$

Number of sequences in which the $1^{st}$ letter appears $2$ times and the $2^{nd}$ letter appears $2$ times:

$$\binom{4}{2}=6$$

Number of sequences in which the $1^{st}$ letter appears $3$ times and the $2^{nd}$ letter appears $1$ time:

$$\binom{4}{3}=4$$

So the total number of such sequences is $6\cdot(4+6+4)=84$.

Comment: Thank you barak. I will need to train myself more on combination.

Comment: @MathDamon: You're welcome, feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

We can first choose the 2 letters, which can be done in $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways.

There are $2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2=16$ words that can be made with these two letters, but we must subtract the two words that only use one letter, so this gives $16-2=14$ possible words; and therefore

there are $6\cdot14=84$ possibilities.